# How to connect Amazon Redshift with WSO2 DSS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, amazon-redshift, wso2-data-services-server

We have amazon redshift instance up and running along with WSO2 DSS. When trying to configure Datasource, I am getting the below error.

> The data source URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers. No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift://hostname:5439/databasename

We have placed com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver jar in components/lib folder and gave Postgresql as Database engine.

What are we missing?

Comment: try using a postgres driver instead that will be fine in most cases

Comment: Tried that too Jon, getting the below error now.

The data source URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers. No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift

Answer (score 0):

Give RDBMS and then Generic as the datasource type as redshift is not listed in the pre-defined datasource types.

According to the [Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) the connection url should be in the following format,

```
jdbc:redshift://endpoint:port/database
```